# Patching a method from other file is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a method say `_select_warehouse_for_order` in `api/controllers/orders.py` file. The method is not part of any class.

Now, I have a new file say `api/controllers/dispatchers.py` where i need to know which warehouse was selected. I am calling `_select_warehouse_for_order` from this file to get this information.

Now, in my test cases, I am patching `_select_warehouse_for_order` like this

```
from unittest.mock import patch, call

def test_delivery_assignment(self, app_context):
    with patch('api.controllers.orders._select_warehouse_for_order') as mock_selected_wh:
        mock_selected_wh.return_value = {}
        app_context.client.set_url_prefix('/v2')
        response = app_context.client.get('/delivery/dispatch')
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

The problem that i am facing is that my patch is not returning empty dictionary. when i started debugging, i noticed that its executed the actual code in `_select_warehouse_for_order`. Am i missing something here?

**Update**:
Here is the code in `dispatchers.py`

```
from api.controllers.orders import _select_warehouse_for_order

@bp.route("/dispatch")
@login_required
def dispatch():
  warehouses = _select_warehouse_for_order(request=request)
    if len(warehouses) == 0:
        logger.info("No warehouse selected")
        return

    logger.info("Selected warehouse: %s", warehouses[0].name)
    # return response
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are testing, including any relevant imports. The issue here is almost always that you are patching the declaration rather than the import. Double check that you patch the method where it is imported and used, not where it is declared.

Comment: I have updated. How would i patch where the method is being imported?

Comment: Use `the.package.where.dispatchers` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must patch where the method is used, not where it is declared. In your case, you are patching `'api.controllers.orders._select_warehouse_for_order'` which is where the method is declared. Instead, patch `'dispatchers._select_warehouse_for_order'` (possibly prefixed with whatever package contains `dispatchers`).

The reason for this is because when you do

```
from api.controllers.orders import _select_warehouse_for_order
```

you declare a name `_select_warehouse_for_order` in `dispatchers.py` that refers to the function which is declared in `api/controllers/orders.py`. Essentially you have created a second reference to the function. Now when you call

```
  warehouses = _select_warehouse_for_order(request=request)
```

you are using the reference in `dispatchers.py`, not the one in `api/controllers/orders.py`. So in order to replace this function with a patch, you have to use `dispatchers._select_warehouse_for_order`.

Notice how `import` is different in python than in Java because we create a new name and assign it to an existing function or class. On the other hand, Java imports tell the compiler where to look for a class when it is mentioned in the code.

Comment: I should have asked this question earlier but forgot. Could you explain the backend of why i have to patch the method where it is being used and not where it got declared. I am from Java background and DI is very common (using spring). an object will be `autowired` and then mocked. Doesn't matter where it was defined/declared. spring will take care of injecting the mock value. how is it different in python or in simple words, whats going on behind the scene here?

Comment: Yah, I can add some words explaining the details there. FYI, patching here isn't the same as DI. We aren't passing parameters to the code that is under test. Instead, we are replacing a function that is called by the code under test. This is more akin to using reflection in Java to replace a method on a class.